# ImportError: cannot import name 'unicode_csv_reader' from 'torchtext.utils'

Tags: python, pytorch, torchtext

I am trying to import these libraries - data, Field, LabelField, TabularDataset, BucketIterator from torchtext but I have this error. Could anyone suggest how to solve this problem please? Thank you so much.

```
from torchtext.legacy import data
from torchtext.legacy import Field, LabelField, TabularDataset, BucketIterator
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [2], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 from torchtext.legacy import data
      2 from torchtext.legacy import Field, LabelField, TabularDataset, BucketIterator

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchtext/legacy/__init__.py:1, in <module>
----> 1 from . import data
      2 from .. import nn  # Not in the legacy folder
      3 from . import datasets

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchtext/legacy/data/__init__.py:3, in <module>
      1 from .batch import Batch
      2 from .example import Example
----> 3 from .field import RawField, Field, ReversibleField, SubwordField, NestedField, LabelField
      4 from .iterator import (batch, BucketIterator, Iterator, BPTTIterator, pool)
      5 from .pipeline import Pipeline

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchtext/legacy/data/field.py:6, in <module>
      4 import torch
      5 from tqdm import tqdm
----> 6 from .dataset import Dataset
      7 from .pipeline import Pipeline
      8 from torchtext.data.utils import get_tokenizer, dtype_to_attr, is_tokenizer_serializable

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchtext/legacy/data/dataset.py:13, in <module>
     11 from torchtext.data.utils import RandomShuffler
     12 from .example import Example
---> 13 from torchtext.utils import download_from_url, unicode_csv_reader
     16 class Dataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
     17     """Defines a dataset composed of Examples along with its Fields.
     18 
     19     Attributes:
   (...)
     25             will have a shared vocabulary.
     26     """

ImportError: cannot import name 'unicode_csv_reader' from 'torchtext.utils' (/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchtext/utils.py)
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to update `torchtext`? Have you checked what version you have?

Comment: the version is 1.12.0.

Answer (score 3):

you can try this:!pip install torch==1.8.0 torchtext==0.9.0